# Create rolling windows in pandas based on window size specified in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that I'd like to sum on a rolling basis where the window is specified by another column.

For example,

| values_to_sum | window_size | rolling_sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 17 |
| 2 | 5 | 16 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 | 19 |
| 4 | 5 | NaN |
| 6 | 4 | NaN |
| 2 | 3 | NaN |
| 4 | 3 | NaN |

Trying to call the column `window_size` within the rolling function results in the error `ValueError: window must be an integer`.

How can I call the column `window_size` on a row-by-row basis for the rolling function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a list comprehension:

```
df["rolling_sum"] = [np.nan 
                     if j + ws > len(df.index)
                     else df.values_to_sum.iloc[j: j+ws].sum()
                     for j, ws in enumerate(df.window_size)]
```

Put `np.nan` if the current index (`j`) plus window size (`ws`) exceeds the dataframe's length (`len(df.index)`); else get the window with `iloc` and `sum` it.

to get

```
   values_to_sum  window_size  rolling_sum
0              1            6         17.0
1              2            5         16.0
2              1            2          4.0
3              3            5         19.0
4              4            5          NaN
5              6            4          NaN
6              2            3          NaN
7              4            3          NaN
```

note: you can pre-define `df_length = len(df.index)` and use it to avoid looking for its length in the comprehension repeatedly.